# Aggregate in R with date column but by the identifier column

Tags: r, aggregate, as.date

I want to `aggregate` (=summarize) my data according to an id-variable. Nonetheless, the date column is getting only NAs after that, I think because it's set up as "Date".

I would like to preserve the dates as they are.

Data (10 first obs):

```
          TUCASEID AGE MALE BLACK YEAR DATASET INTERVIEW_DAY INTERVIEW_DATE
1   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
2   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
3   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
4   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
5   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
6   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
7   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
8   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
9   2.00301e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003
10  2.00301e+13  41    0     0 2003    2003             6      04Jan2003
```

Then, I summarize it with aggregate:

```
timeuse_2003_mean <- aggregate(timeuse_2003[,c("AGE","MALE","BLACK","YEAR","DATASET","INTERVIEW_DAY","INTERVIEW_DATE")],
      by=list(timeuse_2003$TUCASEID),mean)
```

Here the output:

```
  TUCASEID         AGE MALE BLACK YEAR DATASET INTERVIEW_DAY INTERVIEW_DATE
1   2.0030100e+13  60    1     1 2003    2003             5             NA
2   2.0030100e+13  41    0     0 2003    2003             6             NA
3   2.0030100e+13  26    0     0 2003    2003             6             NA
4   2.0030100e+13  36    0     1 2003    2003             4             NA
5   2.0030100e+13  51    1     0 2003    2003             4             NA
6   2.0030100e+13  32    0     0 2003    2003             4             NA
7   2.0030100e+13  44    0     0 2003    2003             1             NA
8   2.0030100e+13  21    0     0 2003    2003             2             NA
9   2.0030100e+13  33    0     0 2003    2003             6             NA
10  2.0030100e+13  39    0     1 2003    2003             4             NA
```

I've got a warning message, probably because the date is formatted as `"as.Date"`, but I do need it in that format and that they also get "summarized" by "aggregate".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked in 2 Steps:

First, I summarized the dataset with sums of the respective variables by the identifier variable `TUCASEID`:

```
timeuse_2003_sum <- aggregate(timeuse_2003[,c("CHILD_CARE_BASIC","CHILD_CARE_TEACH",
                                              "CHILD_CARE_PLAY", ,"OTHER")],
                              by=list(timeuse_2003$TUCASEID),sum_col)

timeuse_2003_sum$TUCASEID <- timeuse_2003_sum$Group.1

timeuse_2003_sum$Group.1 <- NULL

timeuse_2003_sum <- subset(timeuse_2003_sum, select=c(38,1:37))
```

Second, I summarized the dataset with the means of the respective variables. This time I included not only the identifier `TUCASEID`as the group to be summarized by, but also the date variables `INTERVIEW_DATE`:

```
 timeuse_2003_mean <- aggregate(timeuse_2003[,c("TUCASEID","AGE","MALE","BLACK","MARRIED",
                                   by=list(timeuse_2003$TUCASEID, timeuse_2003$INTERVIEW_DATE),mean)

    timeuse_2003_mean$TUCASEID <- timeuse_2003_mean$Group.1

    timeuse_2003_mean$INTERVIEW_DATE <- timeuse_2003_mean$Group.2

    timeuse_2003_mean$Group.1 <- NULL

    timeuse_2003_mean$Group.2 <- NULL
```

In the end, I merged the two summarized datasts by the identifier `TUCASEID`:

```
##################################################################
##     Appending Summary Statistics to single dataset again     ##
##################################################################

timeuse_2003_Summary <- merge(timeuse_2003_mean, timeuse_2003_sum, by = "TUCASEID", all.y = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the opposite of what you have tried. Try :

```
aggregate(TUCASEID~., df, mean)

#  AGE MALE BLACK YEAR DATASET INTERVIEW_DAY INTERVIEW_DATE TUCASEID
#1  60    1     1 2003    2003             5      03Jan2003    2e+13
#2  41    0     0 2003    2003             6      04Jan2003    2e+13
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(TUCASEID = c(2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13, 
2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13, 
2.00301e+13, 2.00301e+13), AGE = c(60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 41L), MALE = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L), BLACK = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), YEAR = c(2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L
), DATASET = c(2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 
2003L, 2003L, 2003L), INTERVIEW_DAY = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L), INTERVIEW_DATE = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("03Jan2003", "04Jan2003"), class = 
"factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: ty a lot for that. It worked. The only problem I have now is that I simplified my data too much to post here. The dataset has 103 variables and only 30 have to be summarized in that way, including those I posted. So, I have the following questions:
1) how to change the syntax to adapt for my case? 
2) what do you mean with "the opposite", why I did the "opposite"? Sorry for the silly question.
3) Is it possible to summarize data with different functions (mean and sum), each for different variables at the same time?
Thank you a lot for your effort.

Comment: @Econ_Spectre 1) If you have multiple columns to be summarised, you can do `aggregate(cbind(TUCASEID, col1, col2)~col3 + col4, df, mean)` and add/remove more columns. 2) "By opposite" I meant, I think you wanted to take `mean` of `TUCASEID` column but in your attempt you had that column as `by` argument which is used to group by a particular column. 3) If you want to apply different functions to different columns I would suggest using `dplyr` which makes it simple to do that.

Comment: I see. Thank you.
1) what is the difference between `TUCASEID~.` and `by TUCASEID`? TUCASEID is the ID of the obs. Comparing that with the original Stata do.file I have, the results seems pretty similar, though the dates and other variables get disturbed.
2) do you know which function of dplyr can do that or what line will be suitable for my case of two functions?

Comment: I am confused. If `TUCASEID` is the ID for which column do you want to calculate the `mean` ?

Comment: I'm actually trying to replicate a Stata code in R.
The Stata code says: 
`collapse (mean) age male black............
(sum) child_care_basic................
.........., by(tucaseid);`
If I understand that correctly, `TUCASEID`, the ID variable, shall be used as reference for the summary, which is composed by `mean` and `sum`, depending on the variable. 
Using `TUCASEID`as reference means "group by a particular column"?

Comment: Using `dplyr`, you can try : `df %>%
  group_by(TUCASEID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(AGE, col1), mean) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(BLACK, col1), sum)` so include all columns to mean in 1st `mutate_at`, all columns to sum in second `mutate_at` and so on.

Comment: I tried it, but I got a lot of warnings and a new dataset with the same number of observations of the original one, that is 412,611 obs. It should has been reduced to 20,720. Earlier, when I was trying to do the summaries with `mean`and `sum` separately with the code in my question, and then, append both, I was getting exactly 20,720 observations, but with a lot of warnings and the ÌNTERVIEW_DATE` column turned to NAs.
I think, your first suggestion might be the way to go, though I got 1,635 obs. instead of the 20,720.
I'm clueless.

Comment: yes, because as we are using `mutate` it does not change the number of rows. So try `df %>% group_by(TUCASEID) %>% mutate_at(vars(AGE, col1), mean) %>% mutate_at(vars(BLACK, col1), sum) %>% slice(1L)` this should reduce the rows.

Comment: Unfortunately, now I have the 20,720 obs, but the 103 variables, not the 68 that are supposed to be there. Moreover, the dates got crashed again. 
Could we work out a R-Base solution, similar to your first one, but anyhow concordant with my first try as in the question. Do you think it is possible? Your first suggestion solved the date problem. Thank you for sharing your knowledge and your valuable time.

Comment: I think I've got it. I just set the date column `INTERVIEW_DATE`as a second group `timeuse_2003_mean <- aggregate(timeuse_2003[,c("TUCASEID","AGE","MALE","BLACK",...,
                               by=list(timeuse_2003$TUCASEID, timeuse_2003$INTERVIEW_DATE),mean)`

After that, I did the same for the `aggregate' with `sum`. Then I just merged the two datasets. I look at a single observation, and all the values corresponded to the original output in Stata, whose code I have. Am I being naive here or can I trust these results? Thank you.

Comment: That's great. Yes, using base R that is a reasonable approach. Glad you figured it out. :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and effort to help a newbie like me.
I'll post it for the other. Would you promote it to an answer? beste regards, my friend

Comment: one last question for you, if I'm not abusing your patience: one single variable has become deturpated. Just one. Do you have any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Not exactly sure maybe try `merge(timeuse_2003_mean, timeuse_2003_sum, by = "TUCASEID", all = TRUE)`. Upvoted your answer.